# What is the role of a Bug reporter?

Tags: bug-reporting, debugging

What is the role of a Bug reporter in reporting bugs and after reporting bugs?  When and how can he get out of the bug-related problem?

Most people get the benefits of the bug report after the bug is confirmed; but this does not ensure each and every reporter's case. For instance, he/she wouldn't get any benefits of bug report if he/she didn't update his system. So he/she should do something. What are they?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Just in case, I think help.ubuntu.com has the right information: [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). If you think something is lacking (or hard to understand) please edit the question and make this clear.

Comment: Actually, I meant the summery of ReportingBugs in help.ubuntu.com. Most people may not read all the things in it. So he must know at least how he could get the problem fixed.

Comment: The best answer might be useful in that page itself as a box item.

Answer (score 0):

By reporting a Bug you are actually helping the Ubuntu team to fix the issue and resolve it in their next update. Reporting bugs don't help you at that time; but may help them to make it easier to find bugs.

Also, Ubuntu is now Open source. So anyone who has some knowledge about how to fix the bug can contribute to fix it, and such persons are called Bug Fixers.

Reporting Bugs help them to understand that some users are experiencing an issue and it needs to be resolved. So their people will work on it and fix it in their next update.

Comment: Vishnu, you didn't neglect this silly thing which is very helpful to novice users. Actually, a brief summery for a common Bug reporter. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding status,delay etc a few words about https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu would be nice.